# Label's text not fading out

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, label, skaction

I'm currently making a very simple 2D soccer game using SpriteKit and Swift. In this game, various power-ups can appear, and these disappear and affect the game in different ways if hit by the ball. When such a power-up, for example the "Super jump" is hit, a label is supposed to say "Super jump", wait one second, and then fade out in 0.5 seconds. The way I've done this is as follows (the `didInteract` function is called when the power-up and ball collides):

```
func didInteract_superJump() {
    notifications.alpha = 1
    notifications.text = "Super jump"
    updateNotificationLabel()
    // code to actually affect the game goes here ... 
}
```

Now the `notifications` label will display "Super jump". The function `updateNotificationLabel` is then called:

```
func updateNotificationLabel() {
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1)) {
        self.notifications.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 0.5))
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + .seconds(1), execute: {
            self.notifications.text = ""
        })
    }
}
```

This might be a bad way of doing it, since it only works *sometimes*. I really have no clue as for what to do. I've read through my code several times, and it seems like is should work – as mentioned, the text fades away sometimes. Other times, it just sits there and never disappears.

This weird error message may or may not be related, but it appeared in my console: Sokar Hedz[1936:57105] [general] __CFRunLoopModeFindSourceForMachPort returned NULL for mode 'kCFRunLoopDefaultMode' livePort: 6271.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SpriteKit, you're better off using the various `SKAction` initializers than trying to do things via GCD.  For your example, something like:

```swift
func updateNotificationLabel() {
    notifications.run(.sequence([.wait(forDuration: 1.0),
                                 .fadeOut(withDuration: 0.5),
                                 .wait(forDuration: 1.0)])) {
        self.notifications.text = ""
    }
}
```

(Beware typos since I haven't tried to compile this, but it should give you the idea.)

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually wasn't aware you could put code in brackets after a sequence, but this works perfectly!

Comment: @Frævik The code in brackets is a closure and is the second argument to `run`. Swift's trailing closure syntax makes this kind of idiom very common.